# Remove header in woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Wordpress 6.3.1 , Twenty Twenty-Three v1.2 theme and Woocommerce 8.0.3. I created child theme and pasted the header.html from \twentytwentythree\parts and let the file header.html blank...   It runs ok in all pages, but in woocommerce checkout page is showing up again the header.

I want to remove header but without CSS. just cleaning the code of the theme.

THis is the code of the header.html in parent theme:

````
<!-- wp:group {"layout":{"type":"constrained"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group">
    <!-- wp:group {"align":"wide","style":{"spacing":{"padding":{"bottom":"var:preset|spacing|40"}}},"layout":{"type":"flex","justifyContent":"space-between"}} -->
    <div class="wp-block-group alignwide" style="padding-bottom:var(--wp--preset--spacing--40)">
        <!-- wp:site-title {"level":0} /-->
        <!-- wp:navigation {"layout":{"type":"flex","setCascadingProperties":true,"justifyContent":"right"}} /-->
    </div>
    <!-- /wp:group -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:group -->```
````

Comment: You may need to copy page.html into child (maybe), as checkout page is a shortcode displayed in a page.

Comment: Yes I did that.  This is the path wp-content\themes\twentytwentythree-child\parts\header.html. The weird thing is that is running ok in all pages but not in woocommerce checkout page. I don´t have more plugins. So I don´t know why this happens.

Comment: Yes very strange … I need to try myself later on.